# DataAdapter.Fill(), Error arise as "Incorrect syntax near ')'"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-connection

When retrieving a datatable from database using the following code in ASP.Net & C#:
The database is located in my local machine.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=CCS90; Initial Catalog=Ribo; Trusted_Connection=True;";
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
myConn.Open();       

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PUR_POHEADER WHERE POID = @POID", myConn);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@POID", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@POID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(request.ReferenceNo);

DataSet DS = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter AD = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, myConn);
//AD.Fill(DS);
AD.Fill(DS, "POTABLE");   //Error arise at this place
DataTable DT = DS.Tables[0];
myConn.Close();
```

When compiler comes to the line `AD.Fill(DS, "POTABLE");`, error occurs at `Incorrect syntax near ')`. What may be the reason?

Comment: what is `insertStatement` in your code?

Comment: wrong 
AD.Fill(DS, "POTABLE");
you use
AD.Fill(DS);

Comment: This error is likely to be a simple typo - a missing bracket or an extra character - but it's not in the code you've posted as the basic syntax of that is fine. I'd guess you haven't shared enough code (or the code you've shared isn't exactly what's on your screen) - the error is possibly in an earlier method in the same file.

Comment: I should had used SqlDataAdapter AD = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
instead of SqlDataAdapter AD = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, myConn);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
SqlDataAdapter AD = new SqlDataAdapter(insertStatement, myConn);
```

replace it with:

```
SqlDataAdapter AD = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
```

and also you are using this overload i think:

```
AD.Fill(DS, "NameOfDataTable");
```

then you can access it like this:

```
DataTable DT = DS.Tables["NameOfDataTable"];
```

insetad of using 0 index.

Comment: The overload of Fill has no bearing on a SQL syntax error.  That just determines whether you can refer to the DataTable by name or not.

Comment: yes but i am clearing this to OP that because he is using down from datatable using index not by name so why he is passing name if he is not even using it...:)

Comment: by putting that statement in an answer you imply that it is relevant to the question, which it isn't in this case.  Also, you tel the OP to try that "to check".  To check what?  That implies that they should check whether that fixes the problem.  Certainly, if you're not using the name of the DataTable then giving it one is pointless but I'd rather suggest using the name instead of the index rather than not providing the name.

Comment: i was not aware you edited and i was correcting it, but in real i was broking it,,again thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with

```
AD.Fill(DS);
```

instead of

```
AD.Fill(DS,"PORTABLE");
```

Also try:

```
SqlDataAdapter AD = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
```

instead of

```
SqlDataAdapter AD = new SqlDataAdapter(insertStatement, myConn);
```

Comment: The overload of Fill has no bearing on a SQL syntax error.  That just determines whether you can refer to the DataTable by name or not.

Answer (score 1):

You create a `SqlCommand` with a `SELECT` statement and then you don't use it.  What is `insertStatement`?  Surely you should be using `sqlCommand`.

Comment: Yes.. I made a mistake by calling insertStatement string value.. thats why it has raised.